# Flycheck error buffer empty for python files in the {package-name}/bin/ directory

Tags: python, buffers

I have this odd problem when I run flycheck on the python files inside the {package-name}/bin directory of my git repository. When I attempt to run flycheck on these files, the buffer with the Flycheck error appears empty and no errors are show. However, when I ran the command from the terminal it works fine.

I can also run flycheck on emacs on *all* other files outside of the {package-name}/bin without issue.

I also tried renaming the files (adding the .py extension) and moving them to another directory, but the problem persists.

Thanks